# Dart: Add dynamic List Json into another dynamic list json where key Bank Name matches

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I wanted add to one dynamic list to another. There is an existing dynamic Bank List in which there is a Bank Name and account details of a customer. Like this

Variable name existedAccountList

```
[
   {
      "BankName":"HDFC",
      "accountsDetails":[
         {
            "Type":"SAVINGS",
            "accReferenceNumber":"HDFC560811476",
            "AccNumber":"XXXXX1476"
         },
         {
            "Type":"current",
            "accReferenceNumber":"HDFC560811476",
            "AccNumber":"XXXXX1476"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

If user creates one or more accounts in HDFC i am storing it like this

Variable name accountList

```
[
   {
      "Type":"SAVINGS",
      "accReferenceNumber":"HDFC002255588",
      "AccNumber":"XXXXX1564"
   },
   {
      "Type":"current",
      "accReferenceNumber":"HDFC002255589",
      "AccNumber":"XXXXX1576"
   }
]
```

I want to merge all the the accounts into  **existedAccountList** on key **accountsDetails**.

I tried to created one function but giving me type error

> Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'JSArray<dynamic>': type 'JSArray<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Map<String, String>>

tried different types solutions but could not find the right solution.

```
List<dynamic> addAccountToExistedBankAccountList(
  List<dynamic> existedAccountList,
  List<dynamic> accountlist,
  String bankName,
) {
for (Map data in existedAccountList) {
    if (bankName.toLowerCase() == data["BankName"].toString().toLowerCase()) {
      data["accountsDetails"].addAll(accountlist);
    }
  }
  return existedAccountList; 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the arguments that you have passed on to the ```addAccountToExistedBankAccountList()``` function

Comment: I resolved this issue by creating third temp variable and adding the required  value in it